# How to pass value in filter generated by ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the ng-repeat of table like below. What I want to do is to pass the value of `t.genre` in filter but it is not working. When the value is get. Its filters the name object of that value and display that into the `td`. For example the value is `10` then the name that will be display is jazz.

Note: When I change the `t.genre` to `10` the output I get is:

`1  simon   10  jazz
 8  betty   20  jazz
 14 archie  30  jazz
 3  jumbo1  40  jazz`

what I want is:

`1  simon   10  jazz
 8  betty   20  rock
 14 archie  30  classic
 3  jumbo1  40  metal`

index.html:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="t in users">
      <td>{{t.id}}</td>
      <td>{{t.username}}</td>
      <td>{{t.genre}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="typ in genre | filter:{ 'id':t.genre}:true">{{typ.name}}</td>
  </tr>
```

and my controller.js:

```
 function Ctrl($scope) {
 $scope.users = [
    {"id":1,"username":"simon","genre":"10"},
    {"id":8,"username":"betty","genre":"20"},
    {"id":14,"username":"archie","genre":"30"},
    {"id":3,"username":"jumbo1","genre":"40"},
 ];

 $scope.genre = [
     {"id":10,"name":"jazz",},
     {"id":20,"name":"rock",},
     {"id":30,"name":"classic",},
     {"id":40,"name":"metal"},
 ];
}
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/dk247c3z/1/

any hlp and suggestions thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the ':true' from the filter and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/qspy5qmt/) what you looking for?

There was an issue with the filter syntax:

```
<td ng-repeat="typ in genre | filter:t.genre">{{typ.name}}</td>
```

Let me know

Answer (score 1):

you can filter it by `t.genre`:

http://jsfiddle.net/maio/dk247c3z/2/